# Is it possible to use CSS to make white pixels in an image transparent or close to it?

Tags: css

Following guides [such as this](https://css-tricks.com/color-filters-can-turn-your-gray-skies-blue/), I have successfully created a monotone image from a full color JPG.

This is the CSS code I am currently using to convert an image to blue monotone:

```
filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(200%) sepia(100%) hue-rotate(-180deg) saturate(200%) contrast(1);
```

What I would like to do from here is lay that image on top of another so that where the image is white, it is transparent. Or at least, close enough.

I have tried using `mix-blend-mode` of which it seems the `darken` parameter is the closest to what I'm after. However, the problem with `mix-blend-mode` is that it doesn't just act on one image. It takes values from both top and bottom image and what is visible or not results from the relationship between the two. This creates unpredictable results when trying to create a general system in which the top and bottom image may be any combination of light and dark.

Also, I'm a little concerned about browser support for `mix-blend-mode`.

[I have created a fiddle here that shows the stage I'm at now.](https://jsfiddle.net/rs4fwk92/)

This may ultimately be impossible, but, **is there any way I can at an image to be transparent depending on how white the pixels are, regardless of the contents of the image underneath?** Is there a way I can get close to this effect?

Comment: Technically using `mix-blend-mode: multiply` will make white pixels transparent, because it multiplies the luminance levels of the current layer’s pixels with the pixels in the layers below. Since it's white, multiplying it with anything gives you white (think along the lines of multiplying 0 with any number). If you want to completely remove the fill from your sample image, simply pump the brightness up to `500%` (an arbitrarily high number) and use multiply as the blend mode: https://jsfiddle.net/L8zkwzva/

Comment: @Terry, thank you, those parameters helped me achieve the effect I wanted. If you convert your comment to an answer, I would like to mark you as correct.

Comment: Glad that my comment helped. I've added a few more details to my answer to make it wholesome :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just porting my comment to an answer since the suggestion worked: you should be using `mix-blend-mode: multiply`. This blend mode will actually make white pixels completely transparent because of how it works—it multiplies the luminance levels of the current layer's pixels (e.g. your hello kitty overlay) with the pixels in the layers below (e.g. your background image).

> Multiply blend mode multiplies the numbers for each pixel of the top layer with the corresponding pixel for the bottom layer. The result is a darker picture.
>
> [Source: Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes)

Since white multiplied with anything produces white (think along the lines of multiplying 0 with any number), you are guaranteed to have 100% transparency and no color changes where the overlaying pixels are white.

The next question is how you should increase the contrast of the image so that even the coloured parts of your figure will turn out white. This is as simple as pumping the brightness up to a sufficiently high level (I've used `500%`, arbitrarily determined), and it seems to work:

[image]

See proof-of-concept fiddle below:

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.blue {
  filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(600%);
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2017/10/14/12/4551406D00000578-4979962-image-a-1_1507978862213.jpg">
<img class="blue" src="http://www.altpress.com/images/uploads/news/Hello_Kitty.jpg" alt="This is a cool picture" width="300px" />
```